# Invalid display of dynamically created table in browsers other than IE

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I created a table containing one row and many cells. Each cell contains another table with many rows to have data like image, link etc.

The final result is a form of product pager as seen here:
http://askmeexpress.com/

My problem is that cells apear like rows (vertically instead of horizontally) in browsers other than IE. Please check the link in IE then in Chrome and see the difference.

Comment: Why? Because you've set TDs to display as block... That's why. And block always breaks the line at the end.

Comment: Please don't use tables for design. They're bulky, not screen-reader-friendly and harder to use as well.

Comment: Please don't link to external sites just like that - add a sample of your code here for purposes of maintaining integrity should the site go dead.

Comment: I've changed tags on your question but next time tag your questions correctly because this doesn't have anything to do with neither C# or Asp.net. Or Javascript for that matter... And as @J.Steen said: next time rather use [JSFiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for your examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You set TDs to display as `block` so they display as such

As per CSS specification Chrome and Firefox display this **correctly** in separate rows. IE displays it incorrectly as table cells (why am I not surprised?).

So in order for your cells to display correctly in Chrome and Firefox and other proper browsers change your cells' display style to `table-cell` rather then `block`. Or at least as empty string:

```
$("YourTdSelector").css("display", "");
```

**Or even better don't use tables for what you're trying to achieve** but rather semantically correct elements. In your case that would be the `UL` element because you're displaying a list of something.

Tables should only be used for tabular data in semantic terms to make your pages accessible to those that need it (i.e. screen readers for the blind).